# Power Automate - Update approval status of SharePoint List item

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have SharePoint list with content approval enabled. When I update the list item using power automate. it approval status gets changed to Pending ,I want to set it to approve. How to do it

I tried the action mentioned in below link

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vHnyf_y62nQ

Answer (score 0):

The internal field name of Approval Status is **_ModerationStatus**. The value 0 equals Approved.

Try something like below:

Uri:
 `_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('<ListName>')/items(<ItemID>)/validateUpdateListItem`

Body:

```
    {
    "formValues":[
    {
        "FieldName": "_ModerationStatus",
            "FieldValue": "0"
    }
    ],
    "bNewDocumentUpdate": false
    }
```

[image]